# Why does 'key' not propagate to react elements in map of {children} elements?

Tags: reactjs, children, react-props, react-component

I'm implementing a component that makes it easier for users to add several items to a page. Since I have several types of items that may be added by a user, I figured having a single component with a "children" parameter would be most useful.

However, the implementation is having trouble with the "key" parameter when mapping over the children elements.

```
function ExpandableSet({
   startingSet,
   itemTitle,
   children
})
{

   const largestId = useMemo(() => {
      return startingSet.reduce((largestId, item) =>
         if (item.id > largestId){
            return item.id
         }
         return largestId
      }, 0)
   }, [])

   const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(largestId + 1);
   const [items, setItems] = useState(startingSet);

   return(
      <div className="expandable-set">
         { items.map( item =>
            <div className="expanded-item" id={item['key']} key={item['key']}> { children } </div>
         )}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() =>
         {
            items.push({"key" : itemCount});
            setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
         }
      }>
         Add {itemTitle}
      </button>
   )
}
```

When `ExpandableSet` is used, it's used like this:

```
...
<div className="container-for-expandable-set">
   <ExpandableSet
      startingSet={[]}
      itemTitle="Some item I want a lot of" />
      <SomeItem opts=opts />
   </ExpandableSet>
</div>
...
```

Since I have no idea how many `SomeItem` elements there will be, there's no way to pass keys at the parent level without managing state there as well. This would defeat the purpose of the `ExpandableSet` component (maybe this is the right answer?)

When this is output, I see the standard `each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop` error.

**HTML Output**

```
...
<div class="expandable-set">
 <div class="expanded-item" id="0">
  <div class="child-template-passed">
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="expanded-item" id="1">
  <div class="child-template-passed">
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
...
```

Why am I still seeing the `key` error?

Comment: Are the keys unique?

Comment: Yep -- I added the "id" into the div so I can make sure they're incrementing appropriately.

Comment: Are the children being passed in an array of components?

Comment: Please, include the example of `startingSet`

Comment: @MosheSommers, not quite sure what you're asking, but I added a code block that shows how the component is used.

Comment: Yep that code block clarifies it

Comment: @macborowy, I added a code block that shows how `startingSet` is initialized (in most cases, it's initialized to an empty array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You begin with a starting set which may have N elements, each with presumably any ID from zero upwards, and then a counter that starts at zero.

So if I add an item to the set via the button on the page, it will have ID zero. But what if an item in the starting set already has an ID of zero? You now have a duplicate ID in the set.

You need to find the largest ID in the starting set, and use this ID plus one as the initial value for `itemCount`.

```
const largestID = useMemo(() => {
  return startingSet.reduce((largestID, item) => {
    if (item.key > largestID) {
      return item.key
    }
    return largestID
  }, 0)
}, [startingSet])

const [items, setItems] = useState(startingSet);
const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(largestID + 1);
```

Comment: This is *basically* an index, but so long as once `id`/`key` is assigned to element it sticks to the data and monotonically increases, and elements are never removed, this *could* be ok.

Comment: @DrewReese, yup -- the id is stored in the array, and if any item is deleted, all other items retain their id's. Counter only ever goes upward.